# cómo colorear el body en resoluciones de celulares y que no me aparezcan espacios blancos?... (Tailwind-Bootstrap)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind

Tengo un App en React, que cuando trabajo en el PC me va todo bien, pero al pasar a resoluciones para celulares, me queda ese cuadrito del `body` a un lado. Siendo que el componente tiene configurado `100vh` tanto en `width` como eh `height`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya van dos veces que me sucede esto, pensé que era porque había hecho algo mal con Tailwind, así que usé Bootswatch, pero me sucede lo mismo.

Lo solucioné dando el mismo color a:

```
html,
body {
  background: #007d9d;
}

.app {
  background: #007d9d;
}
```

Pero estoy coloreando dos elementos. ¿Alguien sabe cómo colorear sólo uno?, ¿o es que así debe hacerse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hace un tiempo yo tuve un problema similar pero el mio era entre resoluciones con cambios muy pequeños.

Primero, ten en cuenta que `100vh` (el 100% de la altura de la ventana) puede no ser suficiente para ocupar todo el espacio en algunos dispositivos debido a la barra de navegación o la barra de estado que ocupan parte de la pantalla. Esto puede causar el espacio vacío.

Para solucionar esto, puedes probar lo siguiente:

1. Utiliza `100%` en lugar de `100vh` para el alto del componente principal. Esto hará que se ajuste al 100% del alto disponible dentro del contenedor.

```css
.app {
  height: 100%;
}
```

2. Asegúrate de que todos los elementos de tu aplicación también tengan una altura del 100% para evitar que haya contenedores con alturas más pequeñas que causen el espacio vacío.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

3. Podrias hacer el responsive utilizando media queries CSS para adaptar el diseño de tu aplicación a diferentes resoluciones de pantalla.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Aqui los estilos ╰(*°▽°*)╯ */
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  /* Aqui los estilos ╰(*°▽°*)╯ */
}
```

Espero alguno te funcione (^///^)